# Can't connect my desktop application to local SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-express

I am using SQL Server authentication for login through SQL Server Management Studio and I can access SQL Server. However, my desktop application cannot establish a connection to the server. I use the following connection string:

```
Server=PC-ADMIN\SQLEXPRESS; Database= Cafe; User=name; Pwd=password;
```

Please help.

Comment: Well - do you get an *error* ? If so, please post that error here - complete and precise error message(s) and all

Comment: the error message I get is : "a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server. The server was not found or was not accessible. verify that the instance name is correct and that sql server is configured to allow remote connection."

Comment: Possibly a firewall issue

Comment: How do I address firewall issue . any suggestion?  thanks @SSS

Comment: Have you tried using `localhost` or `.` as a servername instad of `PC-ADMIN` ?  `Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Cafe; User=name; Pwd=password;`

Comment: To see if it is a firewall issue, disconnect from the internet and then temporarily turn your firewall off to see if your app starts working. If so, then you will need to add a firewall exception: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access

Comment: @Magnus sorry for my late response. It works as you suggested. thanks a lot.